# Stackoverflow while using log4j 1.2.17

Tags: java, maven, log4j, stack-overflow

I'm facing "StackOverflow" error while using the log4j 1.2.17 in my project.

Below is the stack trace of the error

```
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.format(PatternLayout.java:506)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:310)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
        at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.debug(Category.java:260)
        at com.java.oauth.client.JavaOauthWithCertificate.ReadRequiredConfigurationsToObtainToken(JavaOauthWithCertificate.java:42)
        at com.java.oauth.client.JavaOauthWithCertificate.getTokenByCertificate(JavaOauthWithCertificate.java:112)
        at com.test.sre.service.ServiceWrapperImpl.logMessage(ServiceWrapperImpl.java:54)
        at com.test.sre.logging.SREWebServiceAppender.append(SREWebServiceAppender.java:59)
        at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.debug(Category.java:260)
        at com.java.oauth.client.JavaOauthWithCertificate.ReadRequiredConfigurationsToObtainToken(JavaOauthWithCertificate.java:42)
        at com.java.oauth.client.JavaOauthWithCertificate.getTokenByCertificate(JavaOauthWithCertificate.java:112)
```

The part of code inside ReadRequiredConfigurationsToObtainToken at line 42 is

logger.debug(****** validation started *******)

The SRE web service appender is writing the logs to the database. This calls extended AppenderSkeleton class for implementing custom appender. When the code is running, the execution is getting stuck at this point and is throwing the error after certain time.

I have tried to increase stack size and heap size of the JVM but no luck yet.

Below is the log4j configuration set in the properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1, A2, A3

# service will ignore this output, but somebody manually running might be interested
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# also log to a file - again probably not monitored in production but might be handy for debugging
log4j.appender.A2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A2.File=C:\\EnergyTrading\\logs\\debug.log
log4j.appender.A2.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.A2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A2.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

#web service appender - directs log messages to 
log4j.appender.A3=com.test.sre.logging.SREWebServiceAppender

Any help on this error would be greatly helpful.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your appender `SREWebServiceAppender` is using `JavaOauthWithCertificate` which is logging using log4j. That way logging will cause more logging and will always end with stack overflow.

You should update your logging config. You can either (from most to less sensible):

- do not log DEBUG messages in appender `log4j.appender.A3=com.test.sre.logging.SREWebServiceAppender` (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a2.9)
- stop logging DEBUG messages in class `com.java.oauth.client.JavaOauthWithCertificate.ReadRequiredConfigurationsToObtainToken` (I have no idea what category are those)
- stop logging DEBUG messages in root
- remove appender `log4j.appender.A3=com.test.sre.logging.SREWebServiceAppender`